logitech script, re binding to mouse button / macro cant get to work
i have a 180 script macro which works perfectly
MoveAmount = -900
function OnEvent(event, arg)
OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d\n", event, arg)
if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
elseif event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED" then
ReleaseMouseButton(4) -- to prevent it from being stuck on
end
if (event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4) then
for x=1,10,1
do
MoveMouseRelative(MoveAmount, 0)
Sleep(5)
end
  
  

end
end
now im trying to set it up so i  can bind mb5 to a macro. that will press, shift, mb4(script).but when i rebind mb5 to press shift, mb4. it doesnt register. it only presses shift. it likes the macro doesnt pick up the script. or the script is only using true mouse button and disregarding the macro
i tried what i could of my knowledge of macros.
